How do I put the series labels overlaying the graphics series lines in Libreoffice Calc?
As they say, a picture is worth a thousand words... so here goes:
I want the series labels of my Libreoffice Calc spreadsheet to be like this:

Instead of this

Is this possible ? How do I do it ? I've checked everywhere.
For the record the first image is from Google Spreadsheets. If I import the ODS file there it will make it look like Libreoffice Calc style. I want the reverse. I want google spreadsheet's style in Libreoffice Calc, but if I export from Google spreadsheets to Libreoffice it doesn´t have the same style.
